# Need name of 50s sci-fi film with multiple people hovering above ground in suspended animation

Tags: story-identification

I had a still from a 50s sci-fi alien invasion film, the still long since lost, that showed an indoor area [room, shed, etc] where several townsfolk, including a policeman, were in a row in a kind of suspended animation in a standing position - but their feet were not touching the ground. Their eyes were blank, and there were boxes on the floor underneath each of them with wires running to them.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi. We will be much more able to identify this if you give us some key information. When did you have this still? What country was this? What country was the policeman from? Colour?

Answer (score 4):

"I Married A Monster From Outer Space"(1958).

Actually here is the image, I think?

https://thetelltalemind.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/i_married_monster_from_outer_space46.jpg

I remembered this scene from this movie also! If you watch the trailer below, that shot is shown at the 1:25 mark. Don't blink or you'll miss it!